# Segurança do método de autenticação HTTP

Tags: php, autenticação, autenticação-http

Um colega me disse uma vez que usar [esse método de autenticação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.http-auth.php) é muito inseguro. E provou colocando usuário como: **true** e senha: **true**, dentro de um sistema que usava isso e conseguiu passar. Porém acredito que a falta de segurança estava no código que estava mal escrito  e não no recurso.

Gostaria de saber se é possível usá-lo de forma segura, ou isso realmente dá pra burlar, pois neste site estão usando esse tipo de login de janela do sistema, e eu gostaria de ter certeza, justamente para avisá-los do risco:

https://servicos.tecban.com.br/portalSeg/loginAutenticar.do

Comment: Pede pro seu colega avisar, e deixe ele passar o vexame. O endereço que você indicou usa HTTPS. O problema da autenticação por HTTP é que a senha passa aberta pela sua rede, pelo provedor, é tudo o mais pra chegar no destino. O HTTPS quando usado corretamente, criptografa os dados antes do envio (a não ser que você tenha instalada aí aquela "proteção web" dos antivirus, que não é nada mais do que um "man in the middle" do fabricante). Sobre o true, obviamente que a aplicação tinha um problema, ou então um usuário true com senha true ;)

Comment: Mas dá pra usar isso sem https:// de forma segura?

Comment: Dá pra usar qualquer autenticação de senha com e sem HTTPS, mas cai no mesmo problema: sem HTTPS a senha passa aberta. Seja esse tipo de autenticação, ou mesmo um login e senha com formulário na página, a senha passa limpa (ou senha ou o hash usado). O que dá pra fazer pra incrementar, é mandar um _nonce_ que varia de login pra login, e um JS pra fazer o hash, mas é só uma camada extra. O HTTPS é fundamental.

Comment: Entendi, é que eu gosto do estilo de janela, quando quero mostrar um site para um cliente, ele precisa digitar senha... para poder ver... Assim ele fica tranquilo em pensar que ninguém viu antes dele e eu, hehe.

Comment: Lembrando que de navegador pra navegador a janela muda. Dê uma estudada melhor nos prós e contras e pense que em caso de erro, é mais complicado mostrar mensagens amistosas. Além disso, é mais complicado gerenciar o logoff forçado, precisa mandar um status 401 pra pessoa. Não dá pra deslogar fácil do lado do servidor sem mudar as credenciais. Tem caso em que é legal. e tem caso que não fica bom.

Comment: Na minha opinião acredito que a única vantagem de usar esse tipo de autenticação é usar o `CURL`, ou integração com outro software... Porque fica mais fácil usar `curl -u username:password https://` (ou enviar pelo `Authorization: Basic [...]` nos headers), ao invés de fazer um `POST`, que já pode está "ocupado" com envio de outros dados. Enfim, mas para aplicações "comuns" não consigo ver vantagem. Sobre seguro ou não acredito que o problema do  `true`/`true` esteja no código que está autenticando e processando isso e que pode ocorrer com qualquer tipo de autenticação, se feito errado.